# Objective-C: An array of UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uibutton

If I have a large number of buttons set up in Interface Builder, how can I place them into an array via code?

For example, if I have three buttons and in the interface file I define them:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
```

If I want to rename each of these buttons to say "Hello", I want to be able to lump them into an array and then use a function such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.count; i++)
{
    someArray[i].text = @"Hello";
}
```

Could someone please provide information on how this is achieved (if it's possible)?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest solution is to create the buttons in code rather than in Interface Builder. There are other ways to do it, but none are particularly pretty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the buttons in IB are correctly wired to the IBOutlet properties then its as straightforward as:

```
NSArray *buttonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1,button2,button3,nil];
```

Comment: This is what I'm hoping to do. I can't test it out at the moment, but was hoping to write it out before I get home to test it. If it's as simple as this then that would be wonderful! Thanks.

Comment: Although this should work fine - I think the `IBOutletCollection` solution by @Lachlan is worth a look and may be more appropriate. It allows you to do the wiring up straight in Interface builder

Comment: One question if anyone can clarify. Is it a good practice to create an array of 5 buttons like this? `UIButton *buttons[5];` and then use button[0] = ... . Also in comparisons use `if (button[0] == currentButton)` ...

Answer (score 14):

Another approach is to wire the buttons up to an NSArray in Interface Builder.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

Comment: 0o0o I have learnt something new today. I never knew this could be done. awesome! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Keep in mind that the array is not ordered in storyboards, though, it is ordered in nib (xib) files.

Answer (score 8):

The following code will add 5 buttons, each with a new tag and also connect it to an event. The buttons will be placed side by side with a 5px padding:

If you plan on accessing the button outside of the `for{}` scope below, you can define your button in your header, otherwise, you can define it inside the scope. `UIButton * settButton;`

### .m

```
CGFloat staticX         = 5;    // Static X for all buttons.
CGFloat staticWidth     = 60;   // Static Width for all Buttons. 
CGFloat staticHeight    = 56;   // Static Height for all buttons.
CGFloat staticPadding   = 5;    // Padding to add between each button.

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    settButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [settButton setTag:i];
    [settButton setFrame:CGRectMake((staticX + (i * (staticHeight + staticPadding))),5,staticWidth,staticHeight)];
    [settButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [settButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [settButtonView addSubview: settButton];
}
[self.view addSubview: settButtonView];
```

Comment: Helpful post. I think there may be a typo. Should frame x be based on width:    [settButton setFrame:CGRectMake((staticX + (i * (staticWidth + staticPadding))),5,staticWidth,staticHeight)];

Comment: It really depends on your use for this. It's not an OOTB snippet, you will need to make it work for you; changing the frame to work best for your situation will need to be done.

Comment: @WrightsCS my requirements are different but your answer really helped me to resolve my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since you created the buttons directly in Interface Builder, can't you just set them directly in code?

A more general solution would be something like this...if I assume two things: that they are all subviews of the UIViewController's view and that these UIButtons are the *only* UIButtons in that view, you can do something like this:

```
for (UIView *aView in [self.view subviews]) {
   if ([aView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]) {
      UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *) aButton;
      [aButton setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest is to create a single button that you will init and add to a mutable array:

in *.m:

```
UIButton *buttonChar;
```

in your function:

```
buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<lenghtWord; i++) {
    buttonChar = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.2*size.height+(float)i*charFontSize, .5*size.width, charFontSize, charFontSize)];
    buttonChar.tag = i;

    [buttonChar setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
    [buttonChar setTitle:[[NSString alloc] formatWithString:@"Button %d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonChar.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    buttonChar.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    buttonChar.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    buttonChar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    buttonChar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    buttonChar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    [buttonChar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [buttonChar addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [buttonArray addObject:buttonChar];
}
```

buttons are available through:

```
[[buttonArray objectAtIndex:j] setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Since the tag option is also filled, I can always tell what button from the array was touched if it was displayed (buttonAction:withEvent:)

Cheers